# Angular - Component inside a Component Page on the same Module is not a know element

Tags: angular, module, components, lazy-loading

I'm having this issue. I created a 'pages' folder inside my module, and then I created a component cause I want to put it on the page but the CLI is giving me this error message:

```
ng serve -o

⠏ Building...
X [ERROR] NG8001: 'nutricow-categories' is not a known element:
1. If 'nutricow-categories' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.       
2. If 'nutricow-categories' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/nutricow/pages/landing-page/landing-page.component.html:0:0:
      0 │ 
        ╵ ^

  Error occurs in the template of component LandingPageComponent.

    src/app/nutricow/pages/landing-page/landing-page.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
```

This is my nutricow/pages/landing-page:

html:

`<nutricow-categories></nutricow-categories>`

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nutricow-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  styles: ``
})
export class LandingPageComponent {

}
```

And this is my nutricow/components/categories:

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nutricow-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styles: ``
})
export class CategoriesComponent {

}
```

NutricowModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { NutricowRoutingModule } from './nutricow-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { LandingPageComponent } from './pages/landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { EditPageComponent } from './pages/edit-page/edit-page.component';
import { InfoPageComponent } from './pages/info-page/info-page.component';
import { CategoriesComponent } from './components/categories/categories.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LandingPageComponent,
    EditPageComponent,
    InfoPageComponent,
    CategoriesComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NutricowRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ]
})
export class NutricowModule { }
`

And its loaded by LazyLoad:
`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'nutricow',
    loadChildren: () => import('./nutricow/nutricow-routing.module').then( m => m.NutricowRoutingModule )

  },
  {
    path:'**',
    redirectTo: 'nutricow'
  }
];
```

I've tried everything but nothing seems to be working. Does anyones knows what it could be?
Thank you!

I tried to put a selector in another component on the same module. And I'm receiving that is not a known element.

Comment: Is the code available somewhere, so we can test?

Comment: nutricow-categories component must be listed in the declarations section of some module. Is it?

Comment: the ButricowCategoriesComponent mush be declared (in the array `declarations`) in the same module you have declare the LandingPageComponent or in a module (and export it) that is imported (in the array `imports`) in the module where is decalred the LandingPAgeComponent. It's equal this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77902035/how-do-i-add-i-reverse-pipe-to-ngfor-that-uses-an-observeable/77904460#77904460) related to a "pipe". You need remember that a "module" should be "something" that you can "compile" separately the others "module", so you need indicate Angular what components needs

Answer (score 1):

change `loadChildren` to `loadComponent`

```
{
    path: 'nutricow',
    loadComponent: () => import('./nutricow/nutricow-routing.module').then( m => m.NutricowRoutingModule )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1: In  the NutricowModule:,

import { CategoriesComponent } from './components/categories/categories.component';
check the path of the categories component from where the component is imported. Make sure, the path is from the pages folder.

2: import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

schemas: [
CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
],

add the schema in the module.

Comment: Have no related about CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

Answer (score 0):

I found a strange way to fix it.

I imported NutricowModule to the AppModule, save it, and then delete it from the AppModule imports.